# Using sample weights for training xgboost (0.7) classifier

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost, sample

I am trying to use `sample_weight` in `XGBClassifier` to improve the performance of one of our models.

However, it seems like the `sample_weight` parameter is not working as expected. `sample_weight` is very important for this problem. Please see my code below.

Basically the fitting of the model does not seem to take into account the `sample_weight` parameter – it starts at an AUC of 0.5 and drops from there, recommending 0, or 1 `n_estimators`. There is nothing wrong with the underlying data – we have constructed a very good model using sample weights using another tool, getting a good Gini.

The sample data provided does not properly exhibit this behavior but given a consistent random seed throughout we can see that the model objects are identical whether a `weight`/`sample_weight` is provided or not.

I have tried different components from the xbgoost library that similarly have parameters where one can define weights, but no luck:

```
XGBClassifier.fit()
XGBClassifier.train()
Xgboost()
XGB.fit()
XGB.train()
Dmatrix()
XGBGridSearchCV()
```

I have also tried the `fit_params=fit_params` as a parameter as well as `weight=weight` and `sample_weight=sample_weight` variations

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = 
['GB_FLAG','sample_weight','f1','f2','f3','f4','f5'])
df.loc[0] = [0,1,2046,10,625,8000,2072]
df.loc[1] = [0,0.86836,8000,10,705,8800,28]
df.loc[2] = [1,1,2303.62,19,674,3000,848]
df.loc[3] = [0,0,2754.8,2,570,16300,46]
df.loc[4] = [1,0.103474,11119.81,6,0,9500,3885]
df.loc[5] = [1,0,1050.83,19,715,3000,-5]
df.loc[6] = [1,0.011098,7063.35,11,713,19700,486]
df.loc[7] = [0,0.972176,6447.16,18,681,11300,1104]
df.loc[8] = [1,0.054237,7461.27,18,0,0,4]
df.loc[9] = [0,0.917026,4600.83,8,0,10400,242]
df.loc[10] = [0,0.670026,2041.8,21,716,11000,3]
df.loc[11] = [1,0.112416,2413.77,22,750,4600,271]
df.loc[12] = [0,0,251.81,17,806,3800,0]
df.loc[13] = [1,0.026263,20919.2,17,684,8100,1335]
df.loc[14] = [0,1,1504.58,15,621,6800,461]
df.loc[15] = [0,0.654429,9227.69,4,0,22500,294]
df.loc[16] = [0,0.897051,6960.31,22,674,5400,188]
df.loc[17] = [1,0.209862,4481.42,18,745,11600,0]
df.loc[18] = [0,1,2692.96,22,651,12800,2035]

y = np.asarray(df['GB_FLAG'])
X = np.asarray(df.drop(['GB_FLAG'], axis=1))

X_traintest, X_valid, y_traintest, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, 
train_size=0.7, stratify=y, random_state=1337)
traintest_sample_weight = X_traintest[:,0]
valid_sample_weight = X_valid[:,0]

X_traintest = X_traintest[:,1:]
X_valid = X_valid[:,1:]

model = XGBClassifier()
eval_set = [(X_valid, y_valid)]
model.fit(X_traintest, y_traintest, eval_set=eval_set, eval_metric="auc", e 
early_stopping_rounds=50, verbose = True, sample_weight = 
traintest_sample_weight)
```

How do I use sample weights when using `xgboost` for modeling?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that for evaluation datasets weights are not propagated by the sklearn API.

So you seem to be doomed to use the native API. Just replace the lines starting with your `model` definition by the following code:

```
from xgboost import train, DMatrix
trainDmatrix = DMatrix(X_traintest, label=y_traintest, weight=traintest_sample_weight)
validDmatrix = DMatrix(X_valid, label=y_valid, weight=valid_sample_weight)
booster = train({'eval_metric': 'auc'}, trainDmatrix, num_boost_round=100, 
                evals=[(trainDmatrix,'train'), (validDmatrix, 'valid')], early_stopping_rounds=50, 
                verbose_eval=10)
```

**UPD**: The xgboost community is aware of it and there is a discussion and even a PR for it: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1804. However, this was never propagated to v0.71 for some reason.

**UPD2**: After pinging that issue, the relevant code update has been revived and the PR was merged into master in time for the upcoming `xgboost 0.72` release on 1 June 2018

Comment: @Ernie Halberg, kind sir, did you figure out how to get the sample weight working in either xgboost or lightgbm.  I followed the guide on this post using the latest xgboost (0.81) and it still does what you observed - i.e. it starts at 0.5 and drops from there.  Even the native API does not seem to work as intended.